# Set WindowsMediaPlayer to autorun C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-media-player

Hi i'm building my first RPG game in windows form.
I'm currently trying to set a default background music that runs on boot and doesn't stop.
If i set the *axWindowsMediaPlayer* to visible and press play it runs without any problems with that simple line :

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"MyMusic\\ff3.mp3";
    }
```

Its the click event but I can find any "On boot event".
I've read somewhere that the default *axWindowsMediaPlayer.settings.autorun* was true but just to make sure I added that line into my load event :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = true;
```

But still no sound on boot any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [SoundPlayer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx)? If you are building a game it's better this than your solution. So you can load your sound file writing this code:

```
using System.Media;

public SoundPlayer LoadSoundFile(string filename)
{
       SoundPlayer sound = null;

       try
       {
             sound = new SoundPlayer();
             sound.SoundLocation = filename;
             sound.Load();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error loading sound");
       }

       return sound;         
}
```

Then you can `Play()` and `Stop()` your sound when you want.

**EDIT:**

In your case:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadSoundFile(filename).Play();  
}
```

**PS: Remember that you have to convert your .mp3 files to .wav**

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Really like the idea